# Howto use same Layout for Blazor (Serverside) and MVC Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Long story short: I have an asp.net core mvc application that i want to migrate to blazor (serverside).
The idea is to implement new features completely in blazor and slowly re-write the current mvc code blazor.

Therefore i want to achieve something like this:

```
<webapp>/oldfeature --> written in mvc (might use some blazor components as well)
<webapp>/newfeature --> blazor
```

I've been experimenting on a prototype to have mvc and blazor running in the same project, and that worked quiet well. the only issue i'm struggling at the moment is the layout.

My "best" solution consist in the following:

1. "Blazorize" as much as possible from mvc _Layout.cshtml so that it can be re-used in _Layout.cshtml and in Layout.razor
2. Anything that can't be taken over as a component, maintain in _Layout.cshtml and Layout.razor

I'm sure that I'm not the only one having this problem, but I can't find any article on the web. Is there a simpler way to re-use the same layout without needing to maintain the same code twice?

Comment: An example is when you add the authentication to a blazor server app: you get both 'main' pages as you described, and switch between them. There is no magic trick to prevent the duplication of code.